# Подскажите, как сделать клиент для сервера

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Есть уже существующий и рабочий сервер.
Мне надо на Java сделать нагрузочный асинхронный тест для этого сервера,
и первое, что надо сделать - это начальный клиент, чтобы он банально подключался к серверу (находил его, отправлял запрос принимал ответ). 
Подскажите, как реализовать?

Comment: Чисто на сокетах или по http?

Comment: HTTP REST и JSON

Comment: Что за протокол?

Comment: В общем, запрос идет по POST HTTP, а обратно ответ по протокоу REST (JSON) - какой-то защищенный протокол

Comment: Самое простое это использовать [HttpUrlConnection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request) либо [Apache Commons Http Client](http://automation-remarks.com/java-rest-client/).

Comment: На будущее, протокола `REST` не существует. Существует `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, ... и другие протоколы. `POST` - это метод `HTTP` запроса, а `REST` - это что-то вроде типа веб-сервиса. `JSON` - формат данных.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за помощь! Попробую реализовать)